# Usar proxy en Python 3

Tags: python, proxy

Estoy queriendo usar una conexión proxy en Python 3, algo sencillo.

Querría una alternativa al método usado en Python 2

```
proxy = {"http":"http://178.22.148.122:3129"}   
urllib.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip", proxies = proxy).read()
```

Yo intento con

```
urllib.request.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip", proxies = proxy).read()
```

Pero me dice:

> Unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

Gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: como se ejecutaria este script?

Answer (score 5):

Este es uno de los módulos que cambió bastante entre la rama 2 y 3 de Python, hay varias formas:

- Usar la clase [`urllib.request.ProxyHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler), creamos un opener usando la instancia anterior y lo instalamos:

  ```
  from urllib import request

  proxies = {'http':"218.28.112.114:809"}
  url = 'http://www.httpbin.org/ip'

  proxy = request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
  opener = request.build_opener(proxy)
  request.install_opener(opener)
  response=request.urlopen(url)
  print(response.read().decode('utf8'))
  ```
- También podemos hacer uso del método [`set_proxy`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.set_proxy%20de):

  ```
  from urllib import request

  proxy_host = "218.28.112.114:809"
  url = 'http://www.httpbin.org/ip'

  req = request.Request(url)
  req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')
  response = request.urlopen(req)
  print(response.read().decode('utf8'))
  ```